# Why does the program fail to check if an element already exists in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Well, I have to do a grades database including student ID registration, but I'm stuck since I have to do the code with only loops and arrays. I know it will be easy for me to use classes but my teacher wants us to do it with loops :/

Where I'm stuck is at the first case on the switch,I have to ask for a Student ID and validate if it's already in the array that belongs to the ID, I tried using 2 `do while` loops and It worked for a while but even if it's already in the array the ID will be put in the array anyway. I tried asking my teacher but she said that we have already seen loops in class and that I should be able to do it without help.
I'm pretty sure that we saw only basic examples of loops, not this kind of thing where I have to compare 2 arrays.
I will appreciate any help, and sorry for my bad English. 
Thanks for reading the post.

```
public class Reg_Al {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Evaluation[] = {"ID", "Group", "Exam 1", "Exam 2", "Exam 3"};
        int Data[][] = new int[10][6];
        int opc, x, i = 0;
        boolean b = true, a = false;
        do {
            System.out.println("UANL-FCFM");
            System.out.println("MENU");
            System.out.println("1) Student Registration");
            System.out.println("2) Grades");
            System.out.println("3) Calculate Final Grade");
            System.out.println("4) Grades Report");
            System.out.println("5) Final Grade Report");
            System.out.println("6) Exit");
            System.out.println("Choose the desired option:");
            opc = sc.nextInt();
            switch (opc) {
                case 1:
                    do {
                        do {
                            System.out.println("Introduce ID");
                            x = sc.nextInt();
                            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                                if (x == (Data[j][0])) {
                                    System.out.println("Id already exists");
                                    a = true;
                                }
                            }
                        } while (a);
                        Data[i][0] = x;
                        i++;
                    } while (b);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using the Student Database");
                    break;
            }
        } while (opc != 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn to indent your code correctly: it makes it much easier for you and others to read. (Also, I assume that `Datos` is a typo for `Data`, or vice versa).

Comment: In the `do { ... } while (a);` loop, you only ever set `a` to `true` - once it is true, it will never break. Similarly, you never set `b` to `false`, so *that* loop will never exit.

Comment: `Datos` is Spanish or Portuguese for `Data`

Comment: I believe you mean "loops" instead of "cycles"... at least that's the word in English.

Comment: Yes i mean loops, sorry I´m stressed out because I have to do 4 projects this week, and yes about the do while loop, I know it will never break, but i tried to set up different loops and it will not return to ask for the ID again, or even if it ask for it again it will store the repetitive ID on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to arise because in the end of the inner **do-while** loop in the first case of your switch construct, you add the value of **x** to the array anyway. Also, the outer **do-while** loop seems to become infinite as the control variable **b** always has the value **true** and is never changed. Which means that the value of **x** gets added to all indexes of the array. Further, it throws an **ArrayIndexOutOfBounds** Exception when **i**'s value exceeds **9**. Your program is overly complicated. I suggest you to use this simple logic to get the work done easily:

```
switch(opc){
    case 1:

    if(i==9){
        System.out.println("Array is full");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Introduce ID");
        x=sc.nextInt();
        boolean has=false;
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            if(Data[j][0]==x){
                has=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(has)
        System.out.println("ID already exists");
        else
        Data[i++][0]=x; //add the value of x here
    }//outer else

    break; //case 1 break
    ...
    ...
}//switch
```

Note that I added a check for the value of **i** in the beginning of the case. That's to prevent an **ArrayIndexOutOfBounds** Exception when the array is full. I tested the code and it worked fine. I hope it solves your problem.